# Expectation of $ | \{ j \in \Bbb N : \sum_{i=1}^j \alpha_i \leq t \} |$ , $\alpha_i$ iid RV on $[0,\infty)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, poisson-process

Let $(\alpha_i)_{i\in\Bbb N}$ be a collection of i.i.d. random variables on $[0,\infty)$ with density to lebesgue measure. Then, for $t>0, $ let $N(t) := \max\{ k \geq 1 : \sum_{i=1}^k \alpha_i  \leq t\}$.

I am interested if one can say something about $\Bbb E[N(t)]$. I think, heuristically, because $$\Bbb E \left[ \sum_{i=1}^k \alpha_i\right] \leq t \Leftrightarrow k \leq \frac t {\Bbb E[ \alpha_1]}$$ we could  expect that
\begin{align}\tag{1}\label{this} \Bbb E[N(t)] \sim \frac t {\Bbb E[ \alpha_1]}\end{align}

Lately I observed that for $\alpha_1 \sim \text{Exp}(\lambda)$ this holds with equality, more precisely $$\Bbb E[N(t)] = \lambda t$$ while $N(t)\sim$ Poi$(\lambda t)$ is a Poisson-Process. Further this holds for $\alpha_1 \sim$ $\chi^2(2)$ with $$\Bbb E[N(t)] = \frac t 2$$

Is there any approach to the behaviour of (\ref{this}) already? I could not really figure it out, and especially in the calculations for the equations above I used the explicit properties of the distributions of $\alpha_1$.
And my first attempt looked like this:
\begin{align}
\Bbb E[N(t)] = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \Bbb P (N(t) \geq k)  = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \Bbb P \left(\sum_{j=1}^k \alpha_j \leq t \right) = \;\;?
\end{align}
but didn't go further.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renewal_theory

Comment: The _Wald equality_ allows you to compute a related quantity: $$ t\leq E\left[\sum_{i=1}^{N(t)+1}\alpha_i\right] = E[\alpha_1]E[N(t)+1]$$ where $\sum_{i=1}^{N(t)+1}\alpha_i = t + V$ where $V\geq 0$ is the _overshoot_.